# How do I print information from a text file using if statements in python?

Tags: python, printing, text-files

I am new to coding and I am using Python. This is everything I need to do:
[Instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3I7UY.png)

I am struggling to figure out part 2a, my professor said to use if and else statements.
This is what I have so far and all of this my professor said is correct:

```py
def part1():

    createfile=open("Assignment4.txt", "a+")
    createfile.write(f"Player Name          MinsPlayed  Goals   Assists YellowCard\n")
    createfile.write(f"Lionel Messi     1943        19      4       4\n")
    createfile.write(f"Robert Lewandowski   1864        28      6       2\n")
    createfile.write(f"Harry Kane           2017        14      11      1\n")
    createfile.write(f"Jack Grealish        1977        6       10      6\n")
    createfile.write(f"Cristiano Ronaldo    1722        19      3       1\n")
    createfile.write(f"Zlatan Ibrahimovic   1102        14      1       2\n")
    createfile.write(f"Gerard Moreno        1735        14      2       3\n")
    createfile.write(f"Romelu Lukaku        1774        18      6       4\n")
    createfile.write(f"Kylian Mbappe        1706        18      6       3\n")
    createfile.write(f"Erlin Haaland        1542        17      4       2")
    createfile.close()

part1()

def part2():

    filetoopen=open("Assignment4.txt", "r")
    for line in filetoopen.readlines():    
        linetosplit=line.split(' ')   
    filetoopen.close()
```

Comment: So that other users may in the future search for this question and its solution, you should type out 2a. instead of including it in an image

Answer (score 0):

You might find the following code useful:

```py
def part2():
    with open("Assignment4.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    
    players = []
    
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if i == 0:
            continue
        linetosplit = [v.strip() for v in line.split(' ') if v != '']
        #print(linetosplit)
        player_name = linetosplit[0] + ' ' + linetosplit[1]
        mins_played = int(linetosplit[2])
        goals = int(linetosplit[3])
        assists = int(linetosplit[4])
        yellow_card = int(linetosplit[5])
        players.append([player_name, mins_played, goals, assists, yellow_card])
            
    for player in players:
        #print(player)
        
        # 2a (use if-statement)
        if player[1] > 1700:
            print(player[0])
```